# How can I get a string inbetween two known strings?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have the following string (useless parts of the string replaced with `[...]`):

```
[...]
%S A000001 abcdefg
%T A000001 aabbccf
%U A000001 sdfqsfw
[...]
```

I need to get exactly the `abcdefg` part (and the other parts, `aabbccf` and `sdfqsfw`). I've come to the conclusion to use regex.

My thoughts so far: I search for where it matches `%S A000001`, then extract everything until a newline appears. Though I know regex patters, I farily have no idea how to get to this.

I know I could express the line with this pattern:

```
%S A000001 .+\n
```

Well, I still have no idea how to extract the `.+` part.

Any ideas on how to achieve this in C#?

*To clarify the title, I need everything between `$S A000001` and `\n`.*

Comment: Is `A000001` static? Can there be more letters after `%`?

Comment: I only need the three specified cases, `S`, `T`, and `U`, so there's only one letter. `A000001` is a variable, actually, I plan on using string concatenation (`"%S " + aNumber`).

Comment: You may use `Regex.Matches(s, @"(?m)^%[STU] \w+ (.+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Groups[1].Value).ToList();`. Or, to use your variable: `string.Format(@"(?m)^%[STU] {0} (.+)", aNumber)`

Comment: `incomingStringLines.Split('\n')[0].Split(' ')[2]` Separate on the return character first, then on the spaces. This will give you the first line and third value. If you iterate through a length of lines and check `.Split(' ')[2]` to match your anticipated variable, at that point, you can verify it isn't useless portions of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use a RegEx for that. You can just split on the known section of the string.

```
var str = "%S A000001 abcdefg";
var abc = str.Split("A000001")[1].Trim();
```

Of course, you'd be better off having your "known string" as a variable. That can be used to make sure the line contains that part (in the event you're reading a "useless part" of the string).

Granted, this does assume that you're reading from a file where each line is like in your example. This technique can be used on each `.ReadLine()`.

Comment: `abcdefg` is unknown.

Comment: `abcdefg` being unknown is fine. This process takes the initial line, and breaks it up at your "known string". The `[1]` takes the last part of the string, and puts it into your new variable. The first line of your example, the variable `abc` will equal `abcdefg`. On the second line, `abc` will equal `aabbccf`. On the final line, it will be `sdfqsfw`.

Comment: The problem is, before ths `%S`, there are the same numbers, and so are these numbers after `%U`. WIll it work if i change it to `.Split("%S A...`?

Comment: Is it all a single string, or is it a file with several lines?

Comment: I don't see the difference? One file is one string, "split" up by `'\n'` chars. But yes, It's a file im reading with `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`,

Comment: Then instead of using `.ReadToEnd()`, use `.ReadLine()`. That will give you everything split by `\n` characters. Or perform that split yourself. If you have a single line as I showed in my answer, this is one of the easiest ways to find it. You don't want to add the `%S` into your search, because then that only works for a single line. `A0000001` is the only common portion between all of the rows, so split on that. Alternatively, if that can change, split on a space and take the last section of that array.

Comment: I referred to using that with my own code, thanks alot, helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Split you could do something like

```
int slenght = "%S A000001 ".Length;

string str = "%S A000001 abcdefg"; //your line
str = str.Substring(slenght);
```

if you have a variable length

```
string str = "%S A000001 abcdefg"; //your line
int iOfFirst = str.IndexOf(' ');
int iOfSecond = str.IndexOf(' ', iOfFirst + 1);
str = str.Substring(iOfSecond + 1);
```

this also has to be applied to every line

Answer (score 0):

I think Regex is quite a good choice for this sort of awkward string matching.  Here's a pattern that ought to pick up the matches you are after...

```
(?<=%[STU] A000001\s)\w+
```

It's assumed you've configured the Regex as global.

Tested here: https://regex101.com/r/m2JswZ/1

If you have spaces in the text you want to capture, you could capture to the end of each line as follows:

```
(?<=%[STU] A000001 ).*(\n|\z)
```